# Cannot assign to property 'frame' is a 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift

I am stuck with this error in this line:

> frame.size = unwrappedController.view.frame.size

This is my first app, please help me if possible.

Comment: That is very basic. Please read the [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) in the Language Guide.

Answer (score 2):

Your frame variable is probably declared using `let`, which means it cannot be modified once set. Try using `var` instead of `let`.